# On click, Play HTML5 Video and then go to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have short HTML5 animations that I want to play and then go to a specific link.

I found code that is similar to what I need, I just don't know how to alter it for an HTML5 animation.

```
$('#menu a').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var href = this.href;

$('#whatever').animate({
    top: '300px'
}, 500,
function() {
    window.location = href;
});
});
```

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(event) {
    var href = this.href;

    // This will play the video
    document.getElementById("videoPlayerID").play();

    // This will add an event listener that waits for the video to end.
    // Once it does, it calls the goToLink function and feeds it the href
    document.getElementById('videoPlayerID').addEventListener('ended', goToLink(href), false);

    event.preventDefault();
});

function goToLink(href) {
    window.location = href;
}
```